# Unknown phone number

Tags: sim-card, mobile-network, dialer-codes

An app that I need is not recognizing a SIM/Phone number.

...But the problem is not the app:

Before we go: I've visited other forums, but the answers are uneffective, completely unfit, or oriented to old androids.

- If I go to Settings > About phone > Status > SIM Status, I get many *Unknowns*;
- If I go to Settings > Connections > SIM management, the phone number shows *Unknown*;
- I've tested on 5 different phones (see below). This problem happens on three of them, and works as supposed on the other two;
- The phone receives and sends calls and messages;
- I've resetted APN and stuff, as suggested on other sites;
- There is no option to change my own number on any setting

The SIM card is more than two years old.

Below:

- Does not work on a new Xiaomi, nor on a Galaxy A01 (gotta make work on this one). Calls and SMS work normally.
- Used to work on a Galaxy S9. No one can remember when it stopped.
- Works on two motorolas, one old, probably G3, and the other is a G6. Calls and SMS work normally.

**Update:**
it happens with another SIM.
That SIM belongs to the G3 above. Both SIMs works well on the G3 and the G6, none of them has the number identified on the defective ones (Galaxies and Xiaomi).

Comment: How old is the SIM card? How old are the phones you have tested the SIM card in? Is the SIM card working in the phones that show the number?

Comment: Updated the question to add the information you requested : )

Comment: Linking the app would help //Is the app updated to the latest version on all the phones? //If the versions of the app are different, you can  identify the version that works, obtain that version from sites like APK pure, install on other phones (after uninstall of existing app) and check

Comment: Thank you for the attention. Unfortunately, its a proprietary app, only available on our company. Regardless, no function would be available without the login/password. What I can say is that there is only one version, and it's the one we're passing between the phones. The ones that work and the ones that don't. But the app seems innocent to me: Where the phone identifies the number, the app works...

Comment: Sorry but I can't find the devices you mention. There is neither a Galaxy 9 nor an A1. My suspicion would be partial defect SIM card (e.g. because it is twisted or filthy). Also check the contact pads if they are worn-out because of e.g. deep scratches.

Comment: Galaxy S9 and A01. Corrected. The SIM IS over 2 years old, but there are no visible scratches (it stayed inside the phone all the time). Plus, SMS and Calls work on all of the tested phones. Number shows up on two of them. How can one explain this "works on this phone, doesn't work on that phone" ? Android is the variable here, as far as I can see.

Comment: Any other guess ?

Comment: Ins't there an adb command to "write the number" on the SIM or wherever it should be ?